# How to get List from Database to html in python - Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

i have few items/List stored in database  stored as `['First Form Field', 'Second input Field']`

i want all these items of a column as a list in my front end html page
I am getting items as

`ff= form_fields.objects.all()
return render(request,'user/index.html',{'message': welcome,'ff': ff})`

**INDEX:**

```
 {% for x in ff%}
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ x.id}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ x.name }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {% for y in x.text_field %}
              <label>{{ y }}</label>

                    {% endfor %}
            </td>
            <td>
```

**models**

```
class form_fields(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  form_name = models.CharField(max_length= 50, null=True)
  text_field = models.CharField(max_length=255, null= True)
```

I want that saved list to be in that table as list.

Comment: can you put your models details here, your scope?

Comment: added my model class @SnakeFcz

Comment: In which colunm are you storing `['First Form Field', 'Second input Field']`?

Comment: are you storing ['First Form Field', 'Second input Field'] in charfiled ?

Comment: in text_field @PiyushS.Wanare

Comment: yes i am storing them as a charfield. is there any other way to store it too? i am new to python and django @SnakeFcz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create own `ListField` field for resolving this issue

```
from django.db import models
import ast

class ListField(models.TextField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase
    description = "form fields"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if not value:
            value = []

        if isinstance(value, list):
            return value

        return ast.literal_eval(value)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return value

        return unicode(value)

    def value_to_string(self, obj):
        value = self._get_val_from_obj(obj)
        return self.get_db_prep_value(value)

class Form_Fields(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) ## id builtin in django models
    form_name = models.CharField(max_length= 50, null=True)
    form_fields = ListField()


[1]:Form_Fields.objects.create(form_name="test", form_field=['First Form Field', 'Second input Field'])


{% for x in ff%}
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ x.id}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ x.form_name }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {% for y in x.form_fields %}
                    <label>{{ y }}</label>
                {% endfor %}
            </td>
            <td>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change models.py to this:-

```
from django_mysql.models import JSONField, Model

class form_fields(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  form_name = JSONField()
  text_field = models.CharField(max_length=255, null= True)
```

views.py:-

```
form_fields.objects.create(id=id, attrs=['First Form Field', 'Second input Field'],text_field='TextField')

form_fields.objects.filter(attrs=['First Form Field', 'Second input Field'])
```

You are adding array in character fields so you will getting each thing as a character.Other things whatever you have code will work fine.

Comment: This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items.

Comment: and i am using mysql database

Comment: does't help. it stores the null value